# Java compile error with Firebase plugin and concurrent Executors

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

Gradle fails during compile (release and debug) with Android Studio 3.0 and targeting Android O (API 26) with Firebase plugin.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'. >
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;

```
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.0'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to exclude Guava from Firebase plugin.

In your project `build.gradle` change:

```
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.0'
```

to:

```
classpath('com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.0') {
  exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava-jdk5'
}
```

Also if you still get it - try 'Invalidate Cache/Restart'.